# Julia good practices for performance

Tags: optimization, julia

As physics student, we mostly use Fortran for calculation but i wanted to try something new and found about Julia and the fact that it solves some problems of other languages i also found out that theoretically it's as fast as C and wanted to learn it but when i tried to port some code from fortran to Julia i found out it was way slower. As a beginner i know there are a lot of optimizations that can be done. so i wanted to find out and learn good practices and optimizations to apply for the code.

```
is = zeros(64,64)
kp = zeros(Int8, 1,64)
km = zeros(Int8, 1,64)

for i in 1:64
    for j in 1:64
        is[i,j] = 1
    end
end

for i in 1:63
    kp[i] = i+1
end
for i in 2:64
    km[i] = i-1
end
kp[64]=1
km[1]=64
for T in 1:500
    tr::Float32 = T*0.01
    for k in 1:1000
        for i in 1:64
            for j in 1:64
                en :: Float64=-1*is[i,j]*(is[kp[i],j]+is[km[i],j]+is[i,kp[j]]+is[i,km[j]])
                den:: Float64=-2*en
                if (den<0) 
                    is[i,j]=-1*is[i,j]
                end
                x:: Float64=rand()
                p:: Float64=exp(-den/tr)
                if (den >=0)
                    if (p>x)
                        is[i,j]=-1*is[i,j]
                    else
                        is[i,j]=is[i,j]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    m:: Float64=0.
    for i in 1:64
        for j in 1:64
            m=m+is[i,j]
        end
    end
    m=m/(64*64)
    e:: Float64=0.
    for i in 1:64
        for j in 1:64
            ei=-1*is[i,j]*(is[kp[i],j]+is[km[i],j]+is[i,kp[j]]+is[i,km[j]])
            e=e+ei
        end
    end
    e=e/2
    println(tr, " ", abs(m)," ", e)
end
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: A good start is julia's docs page https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/

Comment: 1. You should wrap your code to a function. 2. You do not need type declaration 3. use broadcasting for shorter code. 3. ` is[i,j]=is[i,j]` does nothing

Answer (score 5):

The [Julia manual's Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#) page is a good reference for writing performant code. [How to optimise Julia code: A practical guide](https://viralinstruction.com/posts/optimise/) covers a few things the manual page doesn't, including newer, more advanced tools available now for performance monitoring and tuning.

A [footnote](https://viralinstruction.com/posts/optimise/#fndef:1) on that post also links to other useful blog posts and videos, of which [the Performance Tips page from Julia for Data Science](https://www.juliafordatascience.com/performance-tips/) is probably the most accessible as a beginner. You can consider this a sort of simplified version of the Julia manual's performance tips page, that covers the most important low-hanging fruits when it comes to Julia performance. **This is probably the best place to start** to get a concise, readable overview of the most common performance issues in beginner Julia code, and the ways to solve them.

As for this particular code, everything being in the global scope is probably a big part of the issue and one that's easy to solve - by enclosing it in a function and then calling it.
You can also avoid some of the bounds-checking in the earlier loops by avoiding the loops altogether - `is = fill(1, 64, 64)`, `kp = [2:63; 1]`, `km = [64; 1:63]`; although this probably doesn't affect the performance much for these small arrays here.
Iterating over columns rather than rows i.e. switching the order of `for i in 1:64` and `for j in 1:64` in the nested loops could also be helpful (this one applies to Fortran too, since both Julia and Fortran are column-major in storing matrices).

The other links in the above-mentioned footnote, for the sake of future-proofing, are:

- [High-performance Julia
  by Guillaume Dalle](https://gdalle.github.io/JuliaPerf-CERMICS/),
- [Optimizing Julia code by  Rik Huijzer](https://huijzer.xyz/posts/inference/),
- [7 Julia Gotchas and How to Handle Them by Chris Rackauckas](https://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/7-julia-gotchas-handle/) (a very old post,with code updated for newer Julia versions),

and the YouTube videos

- [Code Profiling and Optimization (in Julia)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h-xVBD2Pk9o),
- [Optimizing Serial Code in Julia 1: Memory Models, Mutation, and Vectorization](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2i7sSRcSIw) ,
- [How to benchmark like a pro in Julia | Tom Kwong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9C7MAAsMMBc)

Comment: There is also  [this one](https://sylvaticus.github.io/SPMLJ/stable/01_-_JULIA1_-_Basic_Julia_programming/0106_-_Further_topics.html#Some-performance-tips) for a quick overview of the various performance tips..